# Unable to update the value using context

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my first time working with Context API in React native and. I can't seem to figure out this simple thing and I've been. trying different examples for hours now.

I have a simple context name `MyContext.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyContext = React.createContext({
    name: '',
    age: ''
});


export default MyContext;
```

I want to update the value of the `name` from a `TextInput` which are. in another class name `Info.js`

```
<TextInput placeholder={"Enter Name"} onChangeText={'WHAT_TO_DO_HERE'} />
<TextInput placeholder={"Enter Age"} onChangeText={'WHAT_TO_DO_HERE'} />
```

What do I need to do in the `onChangeText` sot that the values get updated in `MyContext`?

**UPDATE:**

I've updated `MyContext.js` to:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyContext = React.createContext({
    name: '',
    age: ''
});

export const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [age, setAge] = useState('');

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{ name, setName, age, setAge }}>
            {children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default MyContext;
```

And then in `Info.js` I'm now doing:

```
const { name, age, setName, setAge } = useContext(MyContext);
<TextInput placeholder={"Enter Name"} onChangeText={setName} />
<TextInput placeholder={"Enter Age"} onChangeText={setAge} />
```

Then to check I've another file `Summary.js` where I'm doing:

```
    const { name } = useContext(MyContext);
    <Text>{name}</Text>
```

But the text is still printing `''` empty.

Also in my `App.js`, I've just placed screens in a `NavigationContainer`

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Info Screen" component={Info} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Summary Screen" component={Summary} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Do I need to change anything in the `App.js`?

Answer (score 0):

You will also need a provider which you can also write inside your MyContext.js

```
export const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [age, setAge] = useState('');

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{ name, setName, age, setAge }}>
            {children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

You would then need to wrap your component which need that data inside your provider.

Inside that component you can then access the provider by using:

```
const { name, age, setName, setAge } = useContext(MyContext);
```

Comment: So before the export statement in `MyContext.js` I've added the first block of code from your answer. Then I added `<TextInput placeholder={"Enter Name"} onChangeText={'setName'} />` but it is not working.

Comment: I've updated my question based on what I did.

Comment: You assign onChangeText a string. setName is function, so it has to be `onChangeText={setName}`.

Also you access the wrong data. You already deconstructed your values object, so it has to be `<Text>{name}</Text>`

Comment: I've updated the question with the said changes it's still `' '` meaning it's not updating. `React.createContext...` values.

Comment: Also, I forgot to add the `App.js` class where I've my `NavigationContainer` not sure if it matters but I've added that code as well.

Comment: I believe you still have to wrap your app inside the provider. I think its best practise to only wrap the components which actually need that data. So only these are getting affected by a rerender on state change.

Do you get anything in your console when trying to call setName?

Comment: If I add `console.log(name)` or `console.log(setName)` after `const { name, age, setName, setAge } = useContext(MyContext);` its only prints either empty `' '` or. `undefined` once meaning when the screen loads then when I start typing it doesn't print anything to the console as if it's not being called.

Answer (score 0):

onChangeText takes a function that passes in the new text that is entered. It should look something like this:

```
const { name, age, setName, setAge } = useContext(MyContext);
<TextInput placeholder={"Enter Name"} onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)} />
<TextInput placeholder={"Enter Age"} onChangeText={(text) => setAge(text)} />
```

Keep in mind, when you call setAge(text) the "text" input passes in a string so you may need to convert that to a number if you have any calculations that need to be performed first.